# R, why parLapply works very well on plm, but for lm, it's extremely slow?

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, environment-variables

I'm trying to use **parLapply** to speed up my program.

I have a function

```
ols.models <- function( mydata, temp.expr, temp.expr2) {
    cl <- makeCluster(getOption('cl.cores',8))
    clusterExport(cl,c('mydata'),envir = environment())
    clusterEvalQ(cl,library(plm))

    temp.reg <- parLapply(cl,temp.expr,function(x) {  
        plm(as.formula(x), index = c("ID_","DATE_"), model = "pooling", data = mydata)
    }
    )

    temp.ols.reg <- parLapply(cl,temp.expr2,function(x) lm(as.formula(x),data=mydata))
    # temp.ols.reg <- lapply(temp.expr2,function(x) lm(as.formula(x),data=mydata))

    )

}
```

temp.expr and temp.expr2 are lists with 2,000 formulas.

```
    temp.reg <- parLapply(cl,temp.expr,function(x) {

        plm(as.formula(x), index = c("ID_","DATE_"), model = "pooling", data = mydata)}

    )
```

This above part of code runs perfectly and greatly reduce calculation time. However, my computer stuck at the following piece of code

```
temp.ols.reg <- parLapply(cl,temp.expr2,function(x) lm(as.formula(x),data=mydata))
```

This line is very slow and keeps running for more than 20 mins, so I have to stop it. However, if I just use **lapply**, it's much faster and only takes 1 min to finish.

```
temp.ols.reg <- lapply(temp.expr2,function(x) lm(as.formula(x),data=mydata))
```

I'm wondering why there's such a big difference. **parLapply** works very well for **plm**, but for **lm**, it's extremely slow and memory usage explodes.

Is it because **lm** is from package 'stats' and it's kind of base environment package? Or this is caused by some environment related problems? This confuses me a lot.

Thanks.